# Python TypeError: option values must be strings in Migrator

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic

Migrator Error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> > "/home/arjdu-d-1890/PycharmProjects/git-local-repo/example-flask-crud/venv/bin/flask",
> > line 8, in 
> > sys.exit(main())   File "/home/arjdu-d-1890/PycharmProjects/git-local-repo/example-flask-crud/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py",
> >line 894, in main
> >cli.main(args=args, prog_name=name)   File "/home/arjdu-d-1890/PycharmProjects/git-local-repo/example-flask-crud/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py",
> > line 557, in main
> >return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/arjdu-d-1890/PycharmProjects/git-local-repo/example-flask-crud/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py",
> > line 697, in main
> >rv = self.invoke(ctx)   File "/home/arjdu-d-1890/PycharmProjects/git-local-repo/example-flask-crud/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py",
> > line 1066, in invoke
> >return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))   File "/home/arjdu-d-1890/PycharmProjects/git-local-repo/example-flask-crud/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py",
> >line 1066, in invoke
> >return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))   File "/home/arjdu-d-1890/PycharmProjects/git-local-repo/example-flask-crud/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py",
> >line 895, in invoke
> >return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)   File "/home/arjdu-d-1890/PycharmProjects/git-local-repo/example-flask-crud/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py",
> > line 535, in invoke
> >return callback(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/arjdu-d-1890/PycharmProjects/git-local-repo/example-flask-crud/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/decorators.py",
> >line 17, in new_func
> >return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/arjdu-d-1890/PycharmProjects/git-local-repo/example-flask-crud/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py",
> > line 412, in decorator
> >return __ctx.invoke(f, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/arjdu-d-1890/PycharmProjects/git-local-repo/example-flask-crud/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py",
> > line 535, in invoke
> >return callback(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/arjdu-d-1890/PycharmProjects/git-local-repo/example-flask-crud/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_migrate/cli.py",
> >line 90, in migrate
> >rev_id, x_arg)   File "/home/arjdu-d-1890/PycharmProjects/git-local-repo/example-flask-crud/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_migrate/**init**.py",
> >line 197, in migrate
> >version_path=version_path, rev_id=rev_id)   File "/home/arjdu-d-1890/PycharmProjects/git-local-repo/example-flask-crud/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/alembic/command.py",
> >line 176, in revision
> >script_directory.run_env()   File "/home/arjdu-d-1890/PycharmProjects/git-local-repo/example-flask-crud/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py",
> >line 427, in run_env
> >util.load_python_file(self.dir, 'env.py')   File "/home/arjdu-d-1890/PycharmProjects/git-local-repo/example-flask-crud/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 81, in load_python_file
> >module = load_module_py(module_id, path)   File "/home/arjdu-d-1890/PycharmProjects/git-local-repo/example-flask-crud/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/alembic/util/compat.py",
> >line 83, in load_module_py
> >spec.loader.exec_module(module)   File "", line 678, in exec_module   File
> >"", line 219, in
> >_call_with_frames_removed   File "migrations/env.py", line 22, in 
> >current_app.config.get('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'))   File "/home/arjdu-d-1890/PycharmProjects/git-local-repo/example-flask-crud/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/alembic/config.py",
> >line 218, in set_main_option
> >self.set_section_option(self.config_ini_section, name, value)   File
> >"/home/arjdu-d-1890/PycharmProjects/git-local-repo/example-flask-crud/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/alembic/config.py",
> >line 245, in set_section_option
> >self.file_config.set(section, name, value)   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 1192, in set
> >self._validate_value_types(option=option, value=value)   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 1177, in
> >_validate_value_types
> >raise TypeError("option values must be strings")
> TypeError: option values must be strings

```
Here is the Code 

> **init.py**

from flask import Flask

from app.config import Config

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
class Config(object):
    SECRET_KEY = 'do-or-do-not-there-is-no-try'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = pymssql.connect('192.168.52.75', 'devteam', 'dev@@2017', 'StudDb')
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

from flask_migrate import Migrate

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

from app import routes, models


**Config.py**

import pymssql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

    class Config(object):
        SECRET_KEY = 'do-or-do-not-there-is-no-try'
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = pymssql.connect('192.168.52.75', 'devteam', 'dev@@2017', 'StudDb')
        SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

**Models.py**

from app import db

class Entry(db.Model):
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
class Config(object):
    SECRET_KEY = 'do-or-do-not-there-is-no-try'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = pymssql.connect('192.168.52.75', 'devteam', 'dev@@2017', 'StudDb')
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, nullable=False)
    status = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Entry {}>'.format(self.description)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the stacktrace the error relies in the type of `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI`, which should be a string not and not a [Connection](https://pymssql.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/pymssql.html#pymssql.Connection) object.

Examples:

- `"sqlite:////tmp/test.db"`
- `"mysql://username:password@server/db"`

Comment: can you please tell me SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI String Format i am using pymssql  
Thanks for the Answer

Comment: something like `"mssql+pymssql://<username>:<password>@<server>/<db>"`

Comment: Worked Thanks a lot